# when I try to run a PS script for fail over tests it gives the following error for service fabric

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

/PS script

```
$connection = "localhost:19000"
$timeToRun = 60
$maxStabilizationTimeSecs = 180
$waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec = 10
$serviceName = "fabric:/****.OnServiceFabric.Policy.Deploy"

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster $connection

Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario -TimeToRunMinute $timeToRun -MaxServiceStabilizationTimeoutSec $maxStabilizationTimeSecs -WaitTimeBetweenFaultsSec $waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec -ServiceName $serviceName -PartitionKindSingleton

Pause
```

//the error when I try to run a service

```
PS C:\Temp> C:\Temp\failovertest.ps1
True
   Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario : GetServiceDescription for service fabric:/****.OnServiceFabric.Policy.Deploy with timeout 00:01:00 failed with 2147949517. The error code is not in success & 
retry error codes.
At C:\Temp\failovertest.ps1:9 char:1
+ Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario -TimeToRunMinute $timeToRun -MaxService ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:TestabilityClusterConnection) [Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario], FabricServiceNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeFailoverTestErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Testability.Powershell.InvokeFailoverTestScenario

Press Enter to continue...:
```

I am running it on a VM so in the processes monitor it shows up ****.CloudServices.OnServiceFabric.Host . I have used this too but it doesn't work

Comment: Try making the titte and the body more concise and well formatted

Comment: @Mikhail the path was incorrect . Finally fixed it :-)